# Как манипулировать элементами родительской формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

К примеру есть форма 1 и форма 2, на каждой форме есть кнопка, которая открывает третью форму.

Как из третьей формы манипулировать элементами родительской формы.

Делал так. На первой и второй форме:

```
Form capture = new capture(); capture.Owner = this; capture.ShowDialog();
```

На третьей форме:

```
add_people main = this.Owner as add_people;
```

Но тут мы явно указываем на "add_people", а как можно сделать не указывая имя формы?

Comment: разделите модель и представление, самое время судя вашему вашему вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте старую форму в конструктор новой и уже с ней работайте

Первая форма:

```
Form2 a = new Form2(this);
            a.Show();
```

Вторая:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 a;
        public Form2(Form1 a)
        {
            this.a = a;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            a.Width += 5;
        }
    }
```

Или передайте любой другой элемент.